# load dict w/o text qualifiers

Tags: python, dictionary

I've to load an excel file including a dict like string without text qualifier (`""`) in a column which looks like this:

```
{Item: 0815, sequence: 1, qty: 3, name: some name, comapny: some company}, 
{Item: 4711, sequence: 2, qty: 4, name: some name, company: some company}
```

I've tried to create the dict using the following statement:

```
item_string = dict(item_string)
```

but I receive the following error message

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is
> required

Any ideas how to create the dict based on this string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each line is a dictionary, you can parse it as YAML:

```
import yaml

s = """{Item: 0815, sequence: 1, qty: 3, name: some name, company: some company}, 
{Item: 4711, sequence: 2, qty: 4, name: some name, company: some company}"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    # remove white-space and comma
    clean = line.strip().strip(",")
    # load dictionary using yaml
    d = yaml.load(clean, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'Item': '0815', 'sequence': 1, 'qty': 3, 'name': 'some name', 'company': 'some company'}
{'Item': 4711, 'sequence': 2, 'qty': 4, 'name': 'some name', 'company': 'some company'}
```

Note that [yaml](https://pyyaml.org/), is a third party library and needs to be be installed:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 0):

For a solution in pure python, you can consider something like this:

```
s = "{Item: 4711, sequence: 2, qty: 4, name: some name, company: some company}"

# split the elements and organize them in a tuple:
l = [(i.split(":")[0], i.split(":")[1]) for i in s[1:-1].split(",")]

# take that tuple and generate a dictionary using dictionary comprehension:  
d = {k:v for k,v in l}
```

This shall give you something like this:

```
{'Item': ' 4711',
 ' sequence': ' 2',
 ' qty': ' 4',
 ' name': ' some name',
 ' company': ' some company'}
```

some additional formatting may be needed.